# Get the name of file(s) within last directory and the full directory path using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, subdirectory, nsfilemanager, nsenumerator

I am trying to obtain the name of a file (JSON format but saved without an extension) within the last directory of a given path. Each file is saved with its own unique subpath inside the app's data container.

I also need to get the full path of the file, including the filename.

From what I've read, I believe it is better to use URLs to do this rather than using string paths.

I have tried the following code:

```
do {
    let enumerator = FileManager.default.enumerator(at: filePath, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil)
    while let element = enumerator?.nextObject() as? URL {
    var nexObject = element.lastPathComponent
        print(nextObject)
    }
} catch let error {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

This does seem to iterate through each level of the path until the end. Great, but what is the best way to get the full path, including the filename, other than concatenation of each object from the above?

All advice gratiously received. Thanks!

Comment: Unclear what the problem is. You are the one who is throwing away the URL and turning it into its `lastPathComponent`. If you wanted the whole URL, don't do that. — Also, please always show _real_ code. Copy and paste your actual code into the question. Do not show nonsense that is just typed directly into the question.

Comment: Will do, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `element` is an [URL](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url), if you're interested in the full path name rather than the [last component](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/url/1780317-lastpathcomponent),  just go for:

```
    var nextObject = element.absoluteURL  // instead of .lastPathComponent
```

or just

```
    var nextObject = element.path  // or even relativePath
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, @Christophe (+1)

I've also since spotted that the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/filemanager/2765464-enumerator) for `enumerator(at:includingPropertiesForKeys:options:errorHandler:)` provides a nice example, which can be modifed for my purposes by using additional [resource keys](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlresourcekey) (e.g. name, path, etc.).